# htaccess for the url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hi id like to know how can i write htaccess to make the url below:

`http://localhost:8000/foo/index.php?pageid=EmpDataEntry`

like this

`http://localhost:8000/foo/pageid/EmpDataEntry`

thanks

Comment: There are some good intros to mod_rewrite which I've found useful: http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/ and http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php in particular

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the official mod_rewrite [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) ? Everything is exaplained.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/foo/pageid/([A-Za-z]+)/?$ /foo/index.php?pageid=$1 [L]
```

Remove `/?` if you don't want to allow a trailing slash.

Comment: sorry, just a newbie using htaccess, but could it work even in localhost? thanks.

Comment: Yes. You just need to make sure Apache is parsing `.htaccess` files by specifiying `AllowOverride All` in your `httpd.conf`.

Comment: sorry man, cant get this to work, it seems allowoverride all is ok in apache and I just copied your sample, but still fails, still getting the full url, thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `still getting the full url` ? Did you try accessing the ressource by the desired address ? If it does not work, change `([A-Za-z]+)` by `(.*)`.